# Would these MacBook messaging issues be related to my accounts being compromised?

Tags: macos, email, messages, privacy

A few months ago I was on my Mac computer and noticed that when I went to text myself (I do this from time to time to save messages or photos I want to keep or come back to etc) that the “To” field at the top of the message was a name I’ve never seen.. so clicked on the “contact card” and it was showing my phone number but different name and an email I’ve also never seen. I thought that was Very Bizzare given that information wasn’t in my iPhone and only on my computer… previously it had always said my name.

I assumed maybe my computer was hacked. I cleared everything off computer and reset it. Reset all passcodes…. A few months later. Same thing has happened again, but now it’s a different name/email.

Assuming someone has hacked into my computer. Do texts from Mac get forwarded to email? And If so, how can you tell ? Is there a setting somewhere for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume first of all that it's just something going wrong, rather than 'hacking'. If you want to be very careful, it’s always a good time to review Apple ID security.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102614 (and follow the [“learn what to do link”](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102560) at the bottom of that page once you’ve done all the basics to secure your account)

You're sure this was "My Card" - the card at the very top of the list in Contacts?

I would recommend checking the list of devices associated with your Apple ID, and making sure that there aren't any unknown or unused devices on that list.

Search Mail for the email address used in the card, and see if it comes up.

**Messages > Settings** has checkboxes for the phone numbers and email addresses that can be used to transmit Messages. Have a look and see what's there.

Ideally, you need to let someone who is skilled with Macs (whom you can trust) look over your Mac: there's just not enough information for this to be handled remotely; and the kind of information we need is not the sort of stuff that you want to publicly display.